# The user will log in with the password she entered while registering

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Data comes in but comes as keyword and value. I want the user to login if the value in Firebase is the same as the current value. I just want the value as an integer.**

```
  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
    
                      if(usersReferans != null){
                        Map controlMap = {
                          "register" : controltextEditingController.text.trim(),
                        };
    
                        usersReferans.child("users").once().then((DataSnapshot snap){
                          if(snap.value != null && snap.value == controltextEditingController.value) {
                            print(snap.value);
                          }
                        } );
    
                      }
    
                      } ,       
    
    
                    child: Text("go"),
                ),
```